# Supervisord inet_http_server all iface error

Tags: supervisord

When I try to start supervisord using `inet_http_server` to listen on all interfaces, I get:

```
Error: Could not determine IP address for hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, please try setting an 
explicit IP address in the "port" setting of your [inet_http_server] section.  For 
example, instead of "port = 9001", try "port = 127.0.0.1:9001."
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is modify your supervisord configuration file.

```
sudo vi /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

end of the file you'll see

```
[inet_http_server]
port=*:9001
```

change as;

```
[inet_http_server]
port=0.0.0.0:9001
```